# Can't display :after elements above a div with background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add some style to a form and I'm having trouble creating a shadow below a div/input using an :after pseudo element.

When I place the div/input directly over the , it works as I expected. However, when I try to place it inside another DIV with a background-color, the pseudo-element never gets displayed.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a60k3h6v/)

```css
div.home-header-input {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

div.home-header-input:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #e1e1dc;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -4px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

input.home-header-input {
  margin: 34px 24px 34px 22px;
  color: #324b5a;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 61%;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.i-will-break-everything {
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff39b;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-header-input">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type your text here" class="home-header-input">
</div>

<div class="i-will-break-everything">
  <div class="home-header-input">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type your text here" class="home-header-input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Could you help me figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Z-index -1 might explain this behaviour; I guess your shadow is behind the background color of your wrapping div

Answer (score 3):

```css
div.home-header-input {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

div.home-header-input:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #e1e1dc;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -4px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

input.home-header-input {
  margin: 34px 24px 34px 22px;
  color: #324b5a;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 61%;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.i-will-break-everything {
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff39b;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-header-input">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type your text here" class="home-header-input">
</div>

<div class="i-will-break-everything">
  <div class="home-header-input">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Type your text here" class="home-header-input">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cd2qjgz/)